# hideqr.o:(.rodata+0x58): undefined reference to `ov::node_validation_failure_loc_string[abi:cx11](ov::Node const*)`

Tags: c++, openvino

I want to use Openvino to run my code! the content os Makefile is below:

```
CPP_FLAGS='-std=c++11'
PLAT_HEADER_PATH = $(HIDEQR_INCLUDE) $(OPENVINO_HEADER_ROOT)/ie $(OPENVINO_HEADER_ROOT)/ngraph $(OPENVINO_HEADER_ROOT) \
                    $(RELY_ON_INCLUDE)

PLAT_LIB_PATH = $(OPENVINO_LIB_PATH) $(RELY_ON_LIB_PATH)

PLAT_LIBS:=-ltbb -ltbbmalloc -lopenvino


demo : demo.o hideqr.o
    g++ ${CPP_FLAGS} $^ $(PLAT_HEADER_PATH) $(PLAT_LIB_PATH) $(PLAT_LIBS) -o $@ 

demo.o : demo.cpp
    g++ ${CPP_FLAGS} -c $< -o $@

hideqr.o : hide_pic.cpp
    g++ ${CPP_FLAGS} -c $< $(PLAT_HEADER_PATH) $(PLAT_LIB_PATH) $(PLAT_LIBS)  -o $@
```

Comment: `$(PLAT_LIB_PATH) $(PLAT_LIBS)` are not necessary with `-c`.

Comment: Does `libopenvino.so` have that symbol? Check with `nm -C .../libopenvino.so | grep node_validation_failure_loc`. My money is on it not being compiled with the CXX11 ABI.

Comment: The symbol does exist:

```$ nm -C libopenvino.so | grep node_validation_failure_loc
0000000000fafad7 T ov::node_validation_failure_loc_string[abi:cxx11](ov::Node const*)
```
There might be some misconfiguration in the linker setup. I very much recomment switching to cmake instead of makefiles if that's an option.

Comment: I checked, the libopenvino.so have that symbol, and I try to use cmake, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use CMake to compile OpenVINO application.

You can refer to the [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/blob/master/demos/CMakeLists.txt) in building Open Model Zoo Demos Application as reference.

#Credit to [tomdol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4517806/tomdol).

Comment: OK, I tried it and solved the problem.